# What is the force behind Colin's head (on a pike)

Tags: fables-comics

In "Fables", Rose Red is few time visited - usually in the time of great need - by a ghost of Colin (or to be precise: a ghost of pig's head on a pike)  - first victim of the failed revolution on the Farm. I always assumed that indeed this is just Colin calling from whatever afterlife he has, but when Red is suffering from depression caused by Boy Blue death and Farm is again in need, after she decides to ignore "talking pig's heads", Colin turns into ghost of her mother.

After heart-warming talk about Rose's and Snow White's past, Red says: "I know that you are not my mother or Colin [...] Could you show me who you really are?"

In next panel we see only Rose Red looking stunned saying "Wow!"

So who really is behind those "ghosts"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final issue of the Super Team story arc, Colin is revealed as Hope, one of the great powers (Same as The North wind, etc).

From the gamespot wikia:

> The character, who is from the story of Pandora and Pandora's box, has appeared in several stories; she is the mysterious being who serves as an adviser to Snow White and Rose Red, ***taking the form of Colin, Boy Blue, and Snow and Rose's mother*** (from Snow White and Rose Red). Her true form is first seen, briefly, in an illustration for the Rose Red story arc, when Dunster Happ explains about the great powers. Earlier in the same story arc, Rose asks the spirit to ***show her true form, which it does, but the reader doesn't get to see what Rose sees***. Hope's identity as the spirit is revealed in the final issue of the Super Team story arc, where she explains to Rose Red that hope is neither destiny nor strategy, but that she tries to champion those who can direct their hopes into actions